# Combining Two buttons operation into single button in Visual Studio 2019 & C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

I have created a GUI in Visual Studio where I have two buttons. One button is used to show ip and second button is used to take that ip and run python script.

But I want to merge these both operations into only one button, that if clicked for the first time should show/take the ip, and when clicked a 2nd time, it should trigger the Python script and all that in single button click.

My code is:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var fileName = "C:\\test.txt";
    var sr = new StreamReader(fileName);
    string fileContent = sr.ReadToEnd();

    var startBlock = "hello";
    var endBlock = "exit";

    var ip = ParseForIpRegex(fileContent, startBlock, endBlock);
    myTextBox.Text = ip; //Change this to match your code
}

private readonly string IPV4_PATTERN = "[0-9.]";

private string ParseForIpRegex(string textToSearch, string startBlock, string endBlock)
{
    var pattern = $@"{startBlock}\D*\s*({IPV4_PATTERN}+).*{endBlock}";
    var ms = Regex.Match(textToSearch, pattern, RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    if (ms.Groups.Count > 0)
    {
        return ms.Groups[1].Value;
    }

    return string.Empty;
}

private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var hostname = myTextBox.Text;
    var username = textBox1.Text;
    var password = textBox2.Text;

    var psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
    psi.FileName = @"C:\Python38\python.exe";

    var script = @"C:pythonscript.py";
    //var config_file = file_path;

    psi.Arguments = $"{script} {hostname} {username} {password}";
    psi.UseShellExecute = false;
    psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
    psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    psi.RedirectStandardError = true;

    var errors = "";
    var results = "";

    MessageBox.Show("script processing");

    using (var process = Process.Start(psi))
    {
        errors = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
        results = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    }

    Console.WriteLine("ERRORS:");
    Console.WriteLine(errors);
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Results:");
    Console.WriteLine(results);

    if (errors != "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show(errors);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show(results);
    }
}
```

Please let me know how I can merge this both operation into one. That in one click 1st button operation will perform and after that 2nd in single click.

Comment: why do you need a second event handler. add all code inside the first button click .

Comment: @MidhunMundayadan how please tell me?

Comment: why cant you add all the code inside first event handler after   myTextBox.Text = ip; //Change this to match your code

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you need to keep all buttons, so you dont use args, just call the method:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //DO job

     // simulate the second click
     button1_Click_1(sender, e)  
}

private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //you could test args to check if its coming from first button     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer of Frenchy, or you can add 2 handers on the event...
depending your preference.

```
        this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
        this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click_1);
```

take note that one of the two the designer will add it for you.
So add the second at form_load event (or where u see fit)

Cheers